# HTML input time - open a clock on android

Tags: javascript, android, jquery, html

I have a android app that displays webpages using webviews. And I have a HTML input of type [time].

Currently touching it opens the old style time selector. How can I force it to open the new Clock style selector for android devices?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solution:

I just created a javascript interface to call Android function that opens Timepicker and returns the time. Then callback the js function in the HTML page with the time and elementID to populate.

Answer (score -1):

This would do the tick

```
<input type="time">
```

I tested it on google chrome on android. Here is the current browser support:
https://caniuse.com/#search=type%3D%22time%22